# Access 2016 - Method or data member not found

Tags: ms-access

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Command36_Click()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDefs

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdef = dbs.QueryDefs("qryGetDecisionFieldOfSelectedRecord")
    Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset

    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport "rptApplicationDeclinedLetter", acViewPreview, "qryApplicationLetter"
    End If
End Sub
```

The compile error is triggered at `Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordSet`. Apologies if this is too obvious.

Comment: Not sure what's causing the error, but you could get rid of all the `dbs`, `rs` and `qdf` stuff and just test `If DCount("*", "qryGetDecisionFieldOfSelectedRecord") > 0 Then`

Comment: Thanks. Very nice suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Correct this to:

```
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
```

Comment: Unfortunately still flags the error but Skippy's suggestion is a nice fix.